# Прием информации по строкам - новое значение с новой строки

Tags: php

Допустим, у нас есть такая форма:

```
<form name="info" action="info.php" method="post">
<textarea name="info" id="info" maxlength="1000" style="width: 400px; height: 250px;"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Начали!">
</form>
```

Пользователь вводит в ней информацию, причем ввод по строкам, т.е. с новой строки новое значение. Например, на первой строке он написал "Товар", на второй "Продукт" и т.д.

Как организовать на PHP приём этой информации именно по строкам, т.е. если рассматривать на том примере, чтобы значение "Товар" было в переменной, к примеру $tov1, "Продукт" в переменной $tov2 и т.д.?

Comment: Так выведите то, что вам приходит и посмотрите как лучше разбить. Скорее всего по пробелам там будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо разбить весь текст из textarea на строки, да? Для этого можно использовать php функцию **explode**, возвращающую массив, содержащий разбитый текст:

```
> a$ = explode('\n',<здесь переменная,содержащая текст TextArea>);
```

Или же использовать функцию посложнее - **strtok**, принимающую строку и лексемы,
в соответствии которым надо дробить строку:

```
> $a = <текст из textarea>;
> $str =strtok($str,'\n');  // \n - это перевод строки 
> while($str) {
> echo("<p>"); echo($str); echo("</p>");
> $str = strtok('\n'); }
```

Comment: А что делать с такой проблемой, когда данные передаются в одну строку. Получается там разделители \n не будет и соответственно все данные будут храниться в одной переменной $a[0]?

Comment: Тогда вам надо будет разбивать строку не по переводам, а по пробелам,
то есть не по "\n", а по "\r". 
Вообще, если есть такая проблема, то лучше используйте функцию
"strtok", заменив в ней везде "\n" на "\n\r", тогда у вас текст будет разбиваться и по переводам строк, и по пробелам.

Comment: strtok с \n\r тоже не помогает. Все данные остаются в $a[0].

Comment: Получилось с помощью preg_split.